# Is this subset of GL(C) a sub-group?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

$$G\:=\:GL_2\left(R\right)$$ $$\:N=\left\{A\in G\:;\:A\cdot A^T=I\right\}$$

Is N a subgroup of G?

So the main work here is to prove closure for the opposite.

We want $A^{-1}\in \:G\:;\:A^{-1}\cdot \:\left(A^{-1}\right)^T=I$

So by applying -1 on both sides of the equation and using transpose characteristics $\:A\cdot \:A^T=I$ we get: $$\left(\:A^{-1}\right)^T\cdot \:\:A^{-1}=I$$
And we don't know (as far as I can see, without trying with looking at generally taken matrix from order 2) if matrices from that kind are commutative, are we?

Maybe somebody can show that they are?

Or am I right and this subset isn't a sub-group ? In that case how do I find an example of that kind of matrices (they are not trivial as we see, very specific).

Comment: In fact, this is the subgroup $O(2) \cong \Bbb S^1 \rtimes \Bbb Z_2$ of orthogonal matrices.

Answer (score 4):

If $AA^t=I$, then you can see at once that $A$ is invertible and, therefore, that in fact $A^{-1}=A^t$. It follows then that $A^tA=A^{-1}A=I$ too.

Comment: Of course, it is communicative and that is why we have closure under inversion. Ok, thank you.

Comment: you mean commutative right?

Comment: @user183297, I don't know what you think is commutative. It  isn't.

Comment: Yes, commutative. Why not? We just showed that: A*A^T=A^T * A (= I).

Comment: Well, the two matrices $A$ and $A^{-t}$ commute. Nothing else. I don't know what you say that «of course» anything, really.